# Headphones don't show up after rebooting

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones

If I restart or fresh start my Ubuntu(20.04), my headphones don't function. Until I reconnect it by manually plugging it out and in, the sound comes from the laptop itself. The sound comes to the headphone only after plugging it in. I have searched the solution for this problem a number of times but to no avail.

Comment: What kind of headphones are these? A USB or simple 3.5mm plug type?

Comment: could you edit your question and provide a sound media output panel SS (near to clock taskbar) with connected headphones, please?